# php mail does not send html content

Tags: php, email

For some reason my php mail() function does not send html,

Instead of `<a href="mysite">link</a>` it shows just shows `link` as plain text.

Any ideas?

this is the headers I used:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: My Automated Message <robot@mysite.cc>' . "\r\n";
```

And invoked as follows:

```
try {
    if (@mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "<span style=\"color:#0D0; font:10pt Tahoma;font-weight:bold;\">{$SENT_MESSAGE}</span><br><br>"; 
        return true;
    } else {
        $tmp=error_get_last();
        throw new Exception($tmp['message']);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<span style=\"color:red; font:10pt Tahoma;font-weight:bold;\">Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</span><br><br>";
}
```

I also tried to send the mail without headers, but then again it shows the link as plain text like this: `<a href="mysite">link</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this header

```
  $headers = 'From: Name<address@domain.com>' . "\r\n" .
       'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
       'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
       'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: Then try this one , hope this will help you `$headers = 'From: Name<address@domain.com>' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
           'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`

Comment: nope, it's still the same, the link word is just a plain text.

Comment: I tried on yandex.ru and mail.ru - both get me the same result.

Comment: are you kidding? These are largest providers in Russia. I also used to send and recieve the links just fine, when I send them mail using sockets.

Comment: sorry but that's not an answer, it just looks like you are kidding :)

Comment: try this toooo `$message = rtrim(chunk_split(base64_encode($message)));

$headers = 'From: Abuse Digest Notification<abuse-digest-notification@singlehop.com>' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
           'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`

Comment: wtf lol, it worked - the gmail I mean. looks like my link was also broken, I'll try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 $from='robot@mysite.cc';      
 $headers ='';
 $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'From: '.$from.' '. "\r\n";

 mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```